# Is JSF2 usable in concert with the "Snaps" web UI framework based on Eclipse Virgo?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, osgi, eclipse-virgo

Snaps is a (rather new) web framework growing out of the Eclipse Virgo community that (will) allow dynamic, componentized web UIs by exploiting the OSGi infrastructure. Apparently it is the heir of "Slices", the previous attempt at this.

What I am wondering is whether there is any work ongoing in looking at how JSF (2) can be combined with such an approach? Is this at all possible? If so, is there any concrete work ongoing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no work going on looking at JSF specifically or any other Web framework for that matter. Snaps aims to give you the dynamic runtime ability to compose your web app without restricting your choice of web framework in any way. It definitely doesn't aim to be another web framework.

I know some people have had JSF running on Virgo so I don't see any reason that you can't use it with snaps although I haven't tried it so I can't say for certain. If you do find a problem raise a bug on the Virgo project :)

Chris.

Comment: Sadly JSF tends to not be orthogonal to other technologies. It is not in the same category as plain JSP, Freemaker and Velocity for example. Since it has this entire state model behind it and its own lifecycle it tends to be tricky to integrate with other things. (see Spring and JSF integration, never clean and easy) That's why I was wondering if any specific JSF work was being done/considered.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still interested: 
At the Virgo formus I know there is some guy who does have it running with FancyFaces.

If you might have found another solution, would be glad to hear.

Grts

Comment: Still interested, haven't worked on this myself yet. Do you have a link to the effort you mentioned?

Comment: Violeta has added a working JSF2 (but basic) sample too http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/668847/

Comment: My experimenting got stuck because FaceServlet made snaps invisible to host btw: 
https://github.com/JochenSzostek/FacesServlet.makes.snaps.invisible.to.host

Would be nice to keep this page/question updated imo.